# How to access results from matplotlib's histogram-function

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have a data set which was injected to Matplotlib's plt.hist.
I saved the results of the operation as follows:

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n,bin,patches= plt.hist(data,bins=3)
```

But how can I access the list of lists saved as `patches`?
Could someone please explain to me the concept of silent_list's/patches.Rectangles and how to access the stored data within? I would like to loop over `patches` in order to get the sub-lists for each bin. Similar to:

```
0: [1,4,6,8]
1: [2,3]
2: [5,7,9]
```

Thank you

Comment: As far as I can tell, the individual elements that were used to compute the histogram are not stored in the output of `plt.hist`. Also, I don't get the logic of your selection.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do. It is entirely unclear how you get from the three lists `0: [1,4,6,8]
1: [2,3]
2: [5,7,9]` from your original dataset.

Comment: The logic was indeed confusing. The three lists just represented random examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `patches` returned by `plt.hist` is a list of rectangles. A rectangle has four corners and is a `matplotlib.patches.Patch` with all the corresponding attributes.

You may loop over the patches to manipulate the properties of the bars, e.g. like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[1,2,2,3,4,5,7,7.5,9,8,9]
n,bins,patches= plt.hist(data,bins=3)

for bar in patches:
    print(bar.get_height())
    bar.set_facecolor("pink")
    bar.set_edgecolor("red")

plt.show()
```

However, the patch naturally has no information about where it comes from. So in order to find the histogram data, it is of no use.

In order to find out which bin contains which points from the input data, you may loop over the `bins` and select those points being in the respective bin.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=[1,2,2,3,4,5,7,7.5,9,8,9]
n,bins,patches= plt.hist(data,bins=3)


binlist = np.c_[bins[:-1],bins[1:]]
d = np.array(data)
for i in range(len(binlist)):
    if i == len(binlist)-1:
        l = d[(d >= binlist[i,0]) & (d <= binlist[i,1])]
    else:
        l = d[(d >= binlist[i,0]) & (d < binlist[i,1])]
    print(l)

plt.show()
```

would print

```
[ 1.  2.  2.  3.]
[ 4.  5.]
[ 7.   7.5  9.   8.   9. ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I agree now, that these are really two questions. So I learned somethig. ;-) Your explanation help me. I will use the bins to re-create the lists.

Comment: Concerning the downvote, I guess someone just read the first sentence without looking at the question and answer in detail, so I will remove it.